# PHP do 2 preg_replace in link tag

Tags: preg-replace

I am trying to make a multi preg_replace, not sure if thats the correct function.

I want this outcome

[link]www.mynewhomepage.com(My new homepage)[/link]

to become `<a href=mynewhomepage.com>My New homepage</a>`

I have made this code, which dosent give me what i want

```
   $string = 'i have made a new homepage visit [link]http://myhomepage.dk(My New homepage)[/link]';
$find = array('#\[link\](.+)\[\/link\]#iUs', '#\((.+)\)#iUs');
$replace = array('<a href=$1>', '</a>');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);

echo $result;
```

And it give me this outcome: http://myhomepage.dk>

Can anyone guide me or help me in the right direction of what i am doing wrong? :)

Thanks and happy summer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

`\[link\](.*?)\((.*)\)\[\/link\]`

https://regexr.com/3sc23

It basically matches up to first left parenthesis and also from last parenthesis to the end. Then you put these pieces into capturing groups for referencing them later.

Use `<a href="$1">$2</a>` as substitution

About your original question, your solution had these problems:

For first replacement we should use `<a href="$1`. Note that we use `"` at the beginning of the link but for the moment we do not add it at the end. That way, the nest regexp will be easier.

Then, on the second regexp we should add `">` at the beginning in order to close the  tag. Also you were not using the captured group at all. That would be the replacement: `">$1</a>`

That is, change this line:

```
$replace = array('<a href=$1>', '</a>');
```

to this:

```
$replace = array('<a href="$1', '">$1</a>');
```

Comment: That return the text My New Homepage, but now i wont do the other part, the [link] search ..

Comment: @MarkJacobsen Sorry, I missunderstood your requirements. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @julio, it works just fine! ;) .. i have to find time to learn all about the preg replace expressions, it is such a good tool ! ..

Why the 'm' flag? .. what is the M doing ?

Comment: @MarkJacobsen I'm glad it works for you. You don't need `m` flag anymore on these regexes. `m` flag makes `$`match 'end of line' instead of 'end of string', which was needed on my previous regex version in order to work with several lines of data on regex101.com. It is no longer required on the actual version because I'm matching `[link]` as delimiters. Also, if you are just working with single lines, you don't need the `m` flag as "end of line" will be equal to "end of string". A good source for learning about regexes is https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @MarkJacobsen Also, a general tip: While regexes are powerful, if you feel that your regex is getting too much complicated (even if it works), It may be a good idea to use several simple steps. That will help with maintainance on the future.